# Ending all tmux sessions at once

Tags: tmux

How do I end all tmux sessions with a command?
I do know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> detaches the current session and "exits" in a window. But the server process does not end until the last bit is closed.

Suppose there are 3 sessions with 4 windows each open. I want to close all sessions and restart tmux fresh in a proper way (i.e. not killing the server).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The tmux server will exit by itself once all sessions are gone.

Comment: Read `man tmux` - that led me to `tmux kill-server`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but if you read my question again you will find that I did mention both ways and I was looking for another way. More proper (elegant) than Kill and quicker thatn exit all sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in the following way.

Create a new session named "new":

```
tmux new-session -s new
```

Kill all sessions except the one you just created:

```
tmux kill-session -a -t new
```

However, killing the tmux server and starting a new session is just as good.